# $1^2-2^2+3^2-4^2+…-2016^2+2017^2=2017k$ (Solve for $k$)

Tags: power-series

**Question:**

> $1^2-2^2+3^2-4^2+…-2016^2+2017^2=2017k$
>
> Solve for $k$

**My attempt:**

$$1^2-2^2+3^2-4^2+…-2016^2+2017^2\\
\begin{align}= (1-2)(1+2)+(3-4)(3+4)+…+(2015-2016)(2015+2016)+2017^2 \end{align}
$$

What should I do next?

Comment: Can you simplify $(1-2), (3-4), \dots ,(2015-2016)$?

Comment: @sharding4 Yes I can, It's $-(1+2+3+4+…+2016)+2017^2$

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level. The number 2017, in particular, makes this look like a homework or contest problem, so please provide a specific source.

Comment: Now can you sum the parenthesized expression?

Comment: Well, try something.  1-4=-3;-3+9=6;6-16=-10;-10+25=15$.  See any pattern.  And if $n^2=1+3+5+7+.....+(2n+1)$ does that pattern make some sort of sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by sharding4, simplify each parenthesized difference into $-1$ to achieve:

$$-(1+2+3+4+\dots+2016)+2017^2$$

Then recall the partial sum formula:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n k={n(n+1)\over 2}$$

Then apply:

$$-\left({2016\cdot2017\over 2}\right)+2017^2 = 2017k$$

Divide by $2017$:

$$\require{cancel}{-\left({2016\,\cdot\,2017\over 2}\right)+2017^2 \over 2017} = k$$
$${\cancelto{-1008}{{-\left({2016\,\cdot\,2017\over 2}\right) \over 2017}} + \cancelto{2017}{{2017^2\over 2017}}} = k$$
$$-1008+2017=k$$
$$k=1009$$

Answer (score 2):

A very simple way of seeing this is to write the following:

$$\begin{align} \\
1^2-2^2+\dots-2016^2+2017^2 &= 1+(3^2-2^2)+\dots+(2017^2-2016^2) \\
&=1+(3-2)(3+2)+(5-4)(5+4)+\dots+(2017-2016)(2016+2017) \\
&=1+2+3+...+2016+2017 \\
&=\frac{(2018)(2017)}{2}=2017k \\
\end{align}$$

Which means that $k=\frac{2018}{2}=1009$.